# making whole div tag clickable ,css html anchor tag

Tags: html, css

[image: Accordion]

Hello I have one accordion as you can see in image. I want to make that whole Resources clickable but when I do that , Gyphyicon I am using get messed up.
I want that icon and Resources text in one line.
Here is my html code for this thing:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne2" style="background-color:#3498DB;">
            <h4 style="color:white;" class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a [routerLink]=" ['Resource'] ">Resources</a></h4>

        </div>

    </div>
```

P.S: I already try different css thing in my style.css but it wont work, FYI also I am only practicing on resource thing(see image) not on calculation , that's why calculation is not clickable

Any help Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne2" style="background-color:#3498DB;">
            <h4 style="color:white; display:flex; align-items:center;" class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a [routerLink]=" ['Resource'] ">Resources</a></h4>
        </div>
 </div>
```

In addition to any other solution, I would like to add a flexbox solution. Since the H4 tag is the containing element here, I've adding `display: flex` and `align-items: center` here. The first part will force them next to each other and the second part will make sure the items will be aligned properly.

Be aware this solution is not supported in IE9 or older IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne2" style="background-color:#3498DB;" onclick='window.location.href=your address/route">
        <h4 style="color:white;" class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Resources</h4>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="path">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#collapseOne2" style="background-color:#3498DB;">
      <h4 style="color:white;" class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Resources</h4>

    </div>

  </div>
</a>
```